# ALT + F2 not behaving correctly

Tags: 10.10, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Recently my <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> keyboard shortcut switches my Linux machine to a virtual terminal rather than displaying the run window. I haven't made any specific keyboard changes that could of caused this strange issue.

Rather than having to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>, suddenly all of the virtual terminal commands have suddenly binded to the just the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

What can I do to get them back to their default values?

I'm using Gnome with Compiz enabled

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the ctrl key isn't stuck?

Comment: Ha ha, nope the ctrl key is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be experiencing bug [#520546[image]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/520546).

Possible [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/520546/comments/13):

> Seems that I found the root of that problem. It is in console-cyrillic package. When I removed it, the bug has disappeared.

Alternately, you can run:

`sudo kbd_mode -s`

To fix the problem in 18.04. Unfortunately this is not a permanent fix.